# How to extract links by using nokogiri with filtering

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to get all `*.html` links in a document like this.

```
require 'open-uri'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open "http://example.com")
page.xpath("//a/@href").map{|item| item.value if item.value =~ /.*.html$/ }.compact
```

Can I implement same function with `xpath` method?
I think it would be much simpler if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use Ruby's URI class and use the [`extract`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Parser.html#method-i-extract) method:

```
require 'uri'

html = '
<html>
<body>
http://foo.bar.com
mailto://foo@bar.com
</html>
'
URI.extract(html) # => ["http://foo.bar.com", "mailto://foo@bar.com"]
```

This doesn't parse the HTML, but instead uses regex to look for URL-like patterns. It's a little error-prone, but simple and fast.

Beyond that, it's easy to navigate through XML and find URLs *IF* you know where they are, otherwise you're just shooting in the dark and should use something like `URI.extract` because it's well tested, has a number of patterns it recognizes, and allows you to customize what you want to find. Not using it will cause you to reinvent that wheel.

Your test, looking for `a/@href` will find anchors with `href` parameters, but those aren't necessarily going to be URLs, since JavaScript actions can live there too.

If using Nokogiri and only wanting to look in `<a>` hrefs, I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="http://foo.bar.com/index.html">foo</a></p>
<p><a href="mailto://foo@bar.com">bar</a></p>
</html>
'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.search('a[href]').select{ |n| n['href'][/\.html$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] }
# => ["http://foo.bar.com/index.html"]
```

This uses CSS instead of XPath, which usually results in a more readable selector.

`n['href']` is Nokogiri shorthand for getting the value of a parameter of a node.

`[\.html$/]` is a String shortcut for applying a regex match to that string.

Looking at what you wrote:

```
page.xpath("//a/@href").map{|item| item.value if item.value =~ /.*.html$/ }.compact
```

You're having to use `compact` to clean out unwanted/unexpected `nil` values in your array because of the `if` conditional in `map`. Don't do that; It's reactionary and defensive programming when you don't need to write it that way. Instead, use `select` or `reject` to handle your conditional test, which then feeds only acceptable nodes to `map`, which then transforms them:

```
doc.search('a[href]').select{ |n| n['href'][/\.html$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] }
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I didn't know Nokogiri can treat css selector. I'm going to use `doc.css("a[href$='.html']").map{|n| n['href']}`.

Comment: Yes, that's a more direct way of locating the right hrefs. I forgot about `$=`. Nokogiri allows some jQuery CSS extensions to JavaScript, so don't be afraid to try things. I haven't seen a document that shows us exactly what extensions they implemented, but there might be something out there.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `doc.css` though. `doc.search` will do the same thing, and will transparently use either CSS or XPath selectors, making it easier for you. Then, the only time to specify `css` or `xpath` is when you need to force Nokogiri's understanding of what flavor the selector is, since it's possible to write some that could be one or the other, but will behave differently. I also favor `at` over `css_at` or `xpath_at` for the same reason.